# How to exclude some region from a plot to fit the curve?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a data to fit exponential. The data is a spectra having 3-4 peaks. I want to fit exponential on the tails of those peaks. But when I use f=fit(X,Y,'exp1');, the matlab is fitting the curve for the whole spectra and not for the selected region of the spectra. This is because, I think, the selected region is not at zero of the X axis (I select a region using ginput command, then make it separate to do the curve fit). So, as far as I understood, Matlab is plotting from the zero of the x axis and that way it is making mistake. How to get rid of this and get the selected region of the data fitted with exponential?
%%To read the file and plot the spectra

```
function DA13_07_09;

cdir='\\ST-Computer\data\clusters\';

LsTimes=[0, 29906, 129892, 229878];
ScList.t0_us=LsTimes-3000;
ScList.t0_us(1)=0;
ScList.BinW_us=  [100  , 200    , 200     , 200     ];
ScList.tf_us=LsTimes+10E+3; ScList.tf_us(1)=1E+6;

fname='Xe6_550nm_0030';
rf=0;
if rf
F=ReadMSFile2([cdir, fname, '.dat'], ScList);
eval (['save ', fname, ' F;']);
else
eval (['load ', fname]);
end;
pf=1;
if pf
figure(1); clf;
semilogy(F.data{1}.tt_us/1e+3, F.data{1}.yy_counts, '.-');
PrepFig(1, 'time after injection (ms)', 'counts', fname);

AL=round(min([length(F.data{2}.tt_us), length(F.data{3}.tt_us), length(F.data{4}.tt_us)])*2/3);
tsum=F.data{2}.tt_us(1:AL)-LsTimes(2);
ysum=F.data{2}.yy_counts(1:AL)+F.data{3}.yy_counts(1:AL)+F.data{4}.yy_counts(1:AL);

figure(2); clf;
semilogy(F.data{2}.tt_us-LsTimes(2), F.data{2}.yy_counts, '-', ...
    F.data{3}.tt_us-LsTimes(3), F.data{3}.yy_counts, '-', ...
    F.data{4}.tt_us-LsTimes(4), F.data{4}.yy_counts, '-', ...
    tsum, ysum, '-');
legend({'29 ms', '129 ms', '229 ms', 'sum'});
PrepFig(2, 'time after laser (\mus)', 'counts', fname);
end;

%% To plot and fit the curve
A=F.data{1}.tt_us/1e+3;
B=F.data{1}.yy_counts;
[xclick, yclick]=ginput(2);
tIndex=find(A>=xclick(1,1)&A<=xclick(2,1));
t1=(A(tIndex))';
C1=(log(B(tIndex)))';

f=fit(t1,C1,'exp1');
figure(3);
plot(f,t1,C1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are storing the values from your ginput? What are X and Y? Are they the spectral data?

To fit only a portion of your data, you must create a subset of your data using, for example (this is assuming that X and Y are the full spectral data):

```
fig=figure;
plot(X,Y);
[selectX selectY]=ginput(2); % select a start and end point
% take only the data portion between the start and end points 
% (using min and max in case the user clicks the end point first)
sub_indices=(X>=min(selectX) & X<=max(selectX)); 
subX=X(sub_indices);
subY=Y(sub_indices);
f=fit(subX,subY,'exp1');
```

Comment: The problem is still there. I think, after selection, X values of the data points are not at the zero of the X axis. That is the data begin somewhere around 29 or 29.5. So, when I fit the curve, it is taking X0=0. In my case X0 is not 0! I think the program is written assuming X0=0. Could you please suggest me how to make this correction?

Comment: Can you give more details? `fit` does not assume X0 = 0, fit uses the X values you input. Do you mean that the `X` values from your selection start from 0? You have not shown how you are plotting the figure that they are selected from!

Comment: My data starts from 0 extend up to 300. It is a spectrum. It has peaks at (approximately 29.5, 130 and 230. These peaks has some tails (meaning they are not sharp peaks). I want to fix exponential to these tails. So, I select tail of each peak using ginput. Let it be 'A'. Now, A has X and Y values. Here the values along X axis is not starting at zero (in all the case). So, when I fit 'exp1', I am just getting almost a straight line. When I minimize, I see the exponential decay of the fit lies in the zero of the axis! While the real decay lies around 29.5 or 130 or so...

Comment: done... I've added the code I am using... the first part is just to read the file and plot the spectra. It works well. The trouble starts when I select the peaks and try to fix exponential on their tails.

Comment: It looks like you are picking the peaks from fig 2, since you create that and then use ginput. Fig 2 uses F.data{2}, F.data{3}, F.data{4}, and it has offsets to the time vector. You are fitting using F.data{1} and a time vector with no offsets. Is that what you wanted to do? Are you trying to overlay all the curves in Figure 2? I think you want to be using ginput on Fig 1, not Fig 2? If this is not the case, can you show an example of the figures you are using ginput on, and the values it returns?

Comment: I want ginput from figure1 .. F.data{1} . yes I am trying to overlay all curves on Figure 2. But, for the fit, i want to select peaks from Figure 1 (F.data{1}).

Comment: Also, it is not at all plotting when I remove 'log' in the last section [C1=(log(B(tIndex)))';].

Comment: If you use `figure(1)` before ginput maybe that would help?

Comment: use figure(1) before ginput means?

Comment: Put `figure(1);` on the line before `[xclick, yclick]=ginput(2);`